# SCP not working for OpenShift

Tags: node.js, openshift, scp

I am connected to OpenShift via `rhc ssh <myApp>`. `<myApp>` in this case is `fela`.

```
[fela-basickarl.rhcloud.com 553a...]\> scp nodejs.log 553a...@fela-basickarl.rhcloud.com:~/app-root/logs/
The authenticity of host 'fela-basickarl.rhcloud.com (10.167....)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is cf:ee:...:88:a7.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/lib/openshift/553a.../.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
lost connection
[fela-basickarl.rhcloud.com 553a...]\>
```

I am trying to get a copy of `nodejs.log` on my computer.

Comment: Could you rerun `scp` with the `-v` option, and then edit your question to include the full output that it produces? How are you expecting to authenticate with the remote host? Through an SSH key or through a password? If it's a key, where is the key stored and how are you expecting scp to figure out that it's supposed to use that key?

Comment: We use sftp (or some sftp client such as CyberDuck) and it's been working great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to scp from your gear back into your gear? That doesn't make any sense.   You need to scp from your local workstation to your gear to download a file.  You can't already be ssh'd into your gear and then scp into your gear again, your ssh keys aren't there.

Comment: Ah doh, ok now I understand. So I disconnect and try from the local. I'll try and return with the results.